# Animated oil spill on ocean surface

Tags: ocean-simulation

I'm about to help a client do an animation explaining an invention cleaning oil spill or other floating debris from the surface of the ocean.

Any ideas would much appreciated as to how this could be approached. My thoughts so far is to maybe use dynamic paint to somehow make the oil spill. Maybe use a fluid sim as the brush. Since I've not been able to use the ocean modifier as a canvas maybe I should shrink wrap a subdivided plane onto the ocean and use that as the canvas and bake out an image sequence. Maybe this can be reversed and used as a factor between my ocean shader and oil shader.

What I'm aiming for is the oil spill to be removed almost like it had been sucked away by a vacuum cleaner.

Am I missing something obvious?

An added bonus would be if the solution could be used with Eevee.

[image: Oil spill]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Final

[image: final]

Maybe something like this will be enough for you. It is fairly simple and made only with nodes. Rendered in **EEVEE**.

### Overview

**Ocean**

It's a simple **Plane** with **Ocean modifier** and animated **Time** value. From 1 to 5 trough 150 frames.

[image: modifier]

**Material**

I've used "two parts" material. First one is shrinking circle (distorted) and second is main distortion. At the end of the node setup I've used **Color Ramp** to select ocean and oil colors.

Shrinking is made by animating **Mapping Scale**.

[image: nodes]

Comment: Brilliant! With a little tweaking that will probably do just fine. Quite a bit simpler than the route I was about to embark on. I really need to up my procedural game! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BjörnWallén I'm glad you like it! You can accept and upvote my answer if it is sufficient for you.